# Laravel resource API does not load the updated version of relation data on update endpoint

Tags: laravel

I have `Transaction` model. In that model, there is a `quantity` field and a `foodstuff` relationship.

Then, inside `foodstuff` there is a `stock` field.

I was expecting that if I update the `quantity` in `Transaction` model, it should also update the `stock` in the `foodstuff`. The logic is written in the model and called inside the controller. Please read the commented codes, I put an explanation there to be clear.

`TransactionType.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

/**
 * @method static static in()
 * @method static static out()
 * @method static static cancelled()
 * @method static static returned()
 */
final class TransactionType extends Enum
{
    const in = 'in';
    const out = 'out';
    const cancelled = 'cancelled';
    const returned = 'returned';
}
```

`Transaction.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\TransactionType;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'foodstuff_id',
        'type',
        'quantity',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'foodstuff_id' => 'int',
        'quantity' => 'int',
    ];

    /**
     * Update foodstuff stock based on the given transaction type.
     * 
     * @param  string  $type
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateStock(string $type): void
    {
        $currentStock = $this->foodstuff->stock;
        $quantity = $this->quantity;

        $type == TransactionType::in
            ? $this->foodstuff->update(['stock' => $currentStock + $quantity])
            : $this->foodstuff->update(['stock' => $currentStock - $quantity]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the foodstuff that owns the Transaction
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function foodstuff(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Foodstuff::class);
    }
}
```

`TransactionController.php`

```php
public function store(StoreTransactionRequest $request)
{
    $record = Transaction::create($request->validated());

    $record->updateStock($request->type);

    // This works fine, test passed
    return new TransactionResource($record->refresh());
}

public function update(UpdateTransactionRequest $request, Transaction $transaction)
{
    $oldStock = $transaction->foodstuff->stock;
    $transaction->update($request->validated());

    $transaction->updateStock($request->type);
    $newStock = $transaction->foodstuff->stock;

    // dd(
    //     $oldStock, // 47
    //     $newStock, // 48
    //
    //     // to confirm that the operation is working properly
    //     $request->type, // "in"
    //     $request->quantity, // 1
    //     $oldStock + $request->quantity, // 48
    //     $oldStock + $transaction->quantity, // 48
    // );

    // This one still using the old stock (47), eventhough I refreshed it.
    // Test fails,
    // Failed asserting that 47 matches expected 48.
    $transaction->foodstuff->refresh();
    return new TransactionResource($transaction->refresh());
}
```

`TransactionResource.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class TransactionResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            ...
            ...
            'foodstuff' => [
               'stock' => $this->foodstuff->stock,
                ...
                ...
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

`Feature/TransactionTest.php`

```php
// A test for the store endpoint
public function testWhenUserStoreNewRecordWithTypeOfInItShouldUpdateTheFoodstuffStock()
{
    Sanctum::actingAs(User::factory()->createOne());

    $foodstuff = Foodstuff::factory()->createOne();
    $record = Transaction::factory()
        ->state(['foodstuff_id' => $foodstuff->id, 'type' => TransactionType::in])
        ->makeOne()
        ->toArray();

    $response = $this->postJson(route('transactions.store'), $record);
    $response->assertCreated();
    $response->assertJsonFragment($record);

    $data = $response->decodeResponseJson();

    $computedStock = $foodstuff->stock + $record['quantity'];
    $this->assertEquals($computedStock, $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock']);
}

// A test for update endpoint
public function testWhenUserUpdateNewRecordWithTypeOfInItShouldUpdateTheFoodstuffStock()
{
    Sanctum::actingAs(User::factory()->createOne());

    $oldRecord = Transaction::factory()->createOne();
    $newRecord = Transaction::factory()
        ->state(['foodstuff_id' => $oldRecord->foodstuff_id, 'type' => TransactionType::in])
        ->makeOne()
        ->toArray();

    $response = $this->putJson(route('transactions.update', $oldRecord), $newRecord);
    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertJsonFragment($newRecord);

    $data = $response->decodeResponseJson();

    $computedStock = $oldRecord->foodstuff->stock + $newRecord['quantity'];

    // dd(
    //     $oldRecord->foodstuff->stock, // 47
    //     $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock'], // 47
    //     $computedStock, // 48
    // );

    $this->assertEquals($computedStock, $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock']);
}
```

`Test Result`

```sh
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\TransactionTest
  ✓ when user store new record with type of in it should update the foodstuff stock
  ⨯ when user update new record with type of in it should update the foodstuff stock

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\TransactionTest > when user update new record with type of in it should update the foodstuff stock
  Failed asserting that 47 matches expected 48.

  at tests/Feature/TransactionTest.php:328
    324▕         //     $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock'],
    325▕         //     $computedStock,
    326▕         // );
    327▕ 
  ➜ 328▕         $this->assertEquals($computedStock, $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock']);
    329▕     }
    330▕ 
    331▕     public function testWhenUserUpdateNewRecordWithTypeOfOutItShouldUpdateTheFoodstuffStock()
    332▕     {
  

  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.62s
```

Why is this happening and how can I make it load the updated version of `foodstuff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code and they are all working fine except for your testing logic.

```
$this->assertEquals($computedStock, $data['data']['foodstuff']['stock']);


$data['data']['foodstuff']['stock'] // this one is already returning updated data.

// You're testing like
$this->assertEquals($updatedQuantity + 1, $updatedQuantity);
```

That's why your test failed not because of your code but because of your test logic.

Comment: I'm confused, I did exactly what you do in the first line. Also, would you please explain what is that `$updatedQuantity` doing? You didn't include it in your snippet.

Comment: Ah! I think I got your point, for some reason, eventhough the `$oldRecord` was defined before the API call, it will not query the relation data. Instead, when I do `$oldRecord->foodstuff->stock` it will load a the relation data which in this case already be updated by the API call. Thank you very much!